# Django REST Framework: direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Recipe and Ingredient class where i have a m2m placed on the ingredient model. I tested out the model in the admin panel and was working fine. However when i tried creating them in the shell i got an error(see the error below).

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe, related_name='ingredients')


class IngredientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'amount']
        model = Ingredient



class Recipe(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='recipes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class RecipeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)
        owner = ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        fields = ['owner', 'name', 'description', 'image', 'ingredients']
        model = Recipe
```

**Shell Command**

```
beefsoup = Recipe.objects.create(owner=user, name="beef", description="goot", image="httplo")
tomatoes = Ingredient.objects.create(ingredients=beefsoup ,name='tomatoes', amount=2)
```

**Error**
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use ingredients.set() instead.

Comment: Why `Ingredient` model has `ingredients`? Shouldn't `Recipe` have that property instead?

Comment: I think `ingredients` is a set, why are you setting it to a single receipe, I think you need to add receipe to that set.

Comment: Just want to draw your attention towards : `ingredients` inside `ingredient` with a related name `ingredients`

Answer (score 4):

As the error message and [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create) suggest, your snippet should look this way:

```
  beefsoup = Recipe.objects.create(owner=user, name="beef", description="goot", image="httplo")
  beefsoup.ingredients.create(name='tomatoes', amount=2)
```

Besides that, judging by model & property names, it seems that your relationship design is incorrect. It should rather look this way:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class IngredientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'amount']
        model = Ingredient


class Recipe(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='recipes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients, related_name='recipes')


class RecipeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)
    owner = ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        fields = ['owner', 'name', 'description', 'image', 'ingredients']
        model = Recipe
```

Note that `ingredients` now reside in `Recipe` model.